# Managed Service Identity broken by subscription transfer to other tenant

Tags: azure-managed-identity

We recently moved an Azure subscription from one tenant to another while consolidating all our subscriptions in one tenant. Unfortunately, this broke Managed Service Identity for all our Web Apps, and we are now hesitant to move our remaining subscriptions for fear of having to provision new Web Apps in order to get MSI working again.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or at least a way to delete or reset the identities created by MSI so we can recreate them? That would lead to a little bit of downtime, but that would be preferable to having to come up with new names for all the Web Apps, as that was ultimately the solution we found to getting new identities.

Of course, we would prefer to avoid any downtime at all, but I realize that moving a subscription between tenants (and their directories) is tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filip, thank you for reaching out. We're currently investigating how to make the subscription move a smoother process for MSI enabled resources. Please send me a mail, and we can chat further: ArLuca@microsoft.com

Comment: Was there any actual solution to the OP problem and help avoid recreating resources? Current answer has no reusability value.

Comment: Managed identities do not support subscription migration today. The best workaround solution is to "disable" and "re-enable" the system assigned managed identity, after the subscription has been moved.

For user assigned, you'll need to recreate it.